# Got internship response. Already have different internship. Can I refer a friend?

Tags: professionalism, internship

I applied to a internship with this company. They got back to me today, saying that they were very interested in having me work for them over the summer. The thing is, I already accepted another internship for the summer. I have a similarly qualified friend who is still looking for a summer internship.

Is it bad form for me to politely notify them that I cannot work, and to also suggest they get in contact with him? Is attaching a resume too forward in this scenario?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Saying that you have already selected another internship is fine.  Mentioning that you know someone who may be interested is also fine.  I wouldn't forward the resume.  Instead, I'd offer to give the company your friend's information if they are interested.  If they request the information, then give it to them.

Answer (score 4):

You should inform the other company that you have already selected an internship.  You should do this as soon as possible so that the other company can pursue other candidates.  The longer you leave them waiting, the less polite that your answer is.  You should definitely get back to them one way or another.  Your response to them is short and sweet: "Thank you for your interest.  However, I have already accepted an internship elsewhere."

It is valid for you to suggest that you have a friend who you feel would be a good fit for this position.  Let them decide whether they want to pursue a brand-new candidate, or offer the internship to someone else who they have already had contact with.  You can add the following to the previous: "Based on our conversations, I believe that my friend would be a good fit for this internship.  Would you like me to send you their resume?"